# MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: http

Tags: java, url, oracle10g

I am trying to call a servlet from an Oracle DB and for that I am using a java 1.4 class with an URL call on this form
http://ip:80/serv/Servletg?parameter with

```
url = new URL("http","ip",80,"/serv/Servletg"+parameter);
```

and the following exception is occurred:

java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: http
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:376)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:264)

With using a webbrowser the URL is giving a good response from the webserver.

I can not understand what the problem in this issue.
I am using apache Tomcat on the webserver side.

Thanks for Help

Comment: For starters: why do you use a java 1.4 class in 2010?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the URL overload that only takes a string? IE url = new URL("http://ip:80/serv/Servletg?parameter"); ?

Comment: yes I have the same Error with url = new URL("http://ip:80/serv/Servletg?parameter");

Answer (score 1):

You must add the correct security permissions to get it to work - seems that you are not allowed to access the network!

See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b12021/security.htm

Comment: It works with the webbrowser without https.
Do you mean that I need a security permission on Oracle?

Comment: Maybe I understood you wrong but this is what I think happens: You have an oracle DB running a java method for you right? Problably Oracle uses javas built in permissions when running this method. If not, who is running the method/class?

Comment: Added a url to something interesting.. :)

Comment: I tried the https but the compile is givign me the same error

java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: https 

at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:376)  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:264)

Comment: No no, it is not a secure protocol you need. The java code is **not allowed to connect at all using external protocols** - look at the link.